# Associate specific paths in Atlassian Fisheye with Perforce branch mappings

Tags: branch, perforce, atlassian-fisheye, perforce-branch-spec

Say I have branches `//depot/app/main` and `//depot/app/dev`.

"Dev" was created with a Perforce branch mapping
        `map_main_to_dev`
which has the "view" of
        `//depot/app/main/... //depot/app/dev/...`

This branch mapping shows up as a "branch" in Fisheye.  However, browsing files associated with this branch only shows/highlights files under the `//depot/app/main` path.  Files under `//depot/app/dev` are associated with the "head" branch.

I would like `//depot/app/dev` *not* associated with "head" and instead associated with the branch map `map_main_to_dev` that was used to create it.

The issue is that currently when doing a Crucible review of changes/work done in `dev` and merged to `main`, because of the branch separations, Crucible shows one folder tree under `dev` and a wholly separate tree for `main`.

Currently Crucible will show for the "red bar of revisions" in the diff pane:
        `dev` tree: [some start change#]---[change# for dev work]
      `main` tree: [some start change#]---[change# for merge to `main`]
In some cases for `main` tree it'll show even less helpful revisioning:
      `main` tree: [change# for dev work]---[change# for merge to `main`]
And since the resulting merge to `main` is exactly the same as what's in `dev`, in the case of above it shows "No Change" in the diff pane showing no evidence of work on the `main` tree/branch.

What I want is to only show the folder tree of `main`, and then the changesets under review are listed like
        [some start change#]---[change# for `dev` work]---[change# for merge to `main`]

I suspect for this to work both `dev` and `main` need to be considered as part of the same "branch" of `map_main_to_dev`.  So how do I get that to happen?